# OSX: Is GUI Scripting possible directly from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, scripting

I see many examples with a classical scripting language, but I wonder if it is possible to send those events from an Objective-C application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be possible. Check http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html